# mysqli results not filling in values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've been trying to create an array from a mysqli query that creates a new class 'Book'. When I run this code, it returns the correct number of rows that I have in my database, but it won't display any of the values in the rows. Definitely a newb to a lot of this stuff, any help is really appreciated! Here's the code I'm running. If I just put in a pre-populated array, the code all works great. My problem is getting the values from the database into this array.

```
$db = new db();
        $conn = $db->connect();

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $thearray = array();
        while($array_ar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

            $thearray[] = array(
                $array_ar['username'] => new Book($array_ar['username'], $array_ar['first_name'], $array_ar['last_name']),
            );

        }

        echo 'Rows found: ' . mysqli_num_rows($result);

        return $thearray;
```

Ok, so I var_dump($thearray); and it gives me a multidimensional array, which is why it's returning empty values. I think I need it to return an associative array? Here's what it var_dump($thearray); returns:

```
array(4) {

            [0]=> array(1) {
                ["joshua"]=> object(Book)#6 (3) {
                    ["title"]=> string(6) "joshua" ["author"]=> string(6) "Joshua" ["description"]=> string(9) "Lundquist"
                }
            }

            [1]=> array(1) {
                ["matthew"]=> object(Book)#7 (3) {
                    ["title"]=> string(7) "matthew" ["author"]=> string(4) "Matt" ["description"]=> string(3) "Alm"
                }
            }

            [2]=> array(1) {
                ["roger"]=> object(Book)#8 (3) {
                    ["title"]=> string(5) "roger" ["author"]=> string(5) "Roger" ["description"]=> string(9) "Lundquist"
                }
            }

            [3]=> array(1) {
                ["norm"]=> object(Book)#9 (3) {
                    ["title"]=> string(4) "norm" ["author"]=> string(4) "Norm" ["description"]=> string(5) "Shupe"
                }
            }

        }
```

Next I thought I would take a look at what the var_dump(); for my  hard-coded array looks like, and it output this (this one works):

```
array(3) {

        ["Jungle Book"]=> object(Book)#3 (3) {
            ["title"]=> string(11) "Jungle Book" ["author"]=> string(10) "R. Kipling" ["description"]=> string(15) "A classic book."
        }

        ["Moonwalker"]=> object(Book)#4 (3) {
            ["title"]=> string(10) "Moonwalker" ["author"]=> string(9) "J. Walker" ["description"]=> string(7) "another"
        }

        ["PHP for Dummies"]=> object(Book)#5 (3) {
            ["title"]=> string(15) "PHP for Dummies" ["author"]=> string(14) "Some Smart Guy" ["description"]=> string(18) "and the final one."
        }

    }
```

It makes sense to me what's happening, but I'm not sure how to fix my code. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Since you've already put a echo/prinft "debugger" into your code, what does `var_dump($thearray);` right before `return $thearray;` print? Do you use [error_reporting=E_ALL|E_STRICT](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and watch the [php error log](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)?

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and check for any warnings.

Comment: I added the var_dump(); and noted the changes above. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem.

```
$thearray[] = array(
    $array_ar['username'] => new Book(
        $array_ar['username'], $array_ar['first_name'], $array_ar['last_name']),
);
```

It looks like the differences between what you're getting and what you want is 1) You're wrapping the input to `$thearray` in an extra `array()` layer, and 2) You won't get string keys like you have in your hard-coded array if you just add the items using `[]`.

Try it like this instead:

```
// use the username as a key, since that is what it looks like you're using as the 'title'
$thearray[$array_ar['username']] = new Book(
    $array_ar['username'], $array_ar['first_name'], $array_ar['last_name']);
```

Comment: That didn't quite seem to work, but it got me looking at the problem a little differently. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't Panic's answer got me looking in the right direction. I needed to create an associative array, not a multidimensional array. At first I was accidentally creating the multidimensional array by setting $thearray equal to "array();". By removing that, it filled in the values correctly. Thanks again for the help!

```
    $db = new db();
    $conn = $db->connect();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $thearray = array();
    while($array_ar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $title = $array_ar['username'];
        $author = $array_ar['username'];
        $description = $array_ar['username'];

        $thearray[] = $title = new Book($title, $author, $description);

    }
    var_dump($thearray);
    echo 'Rows found: ' . mysqli_num_rows($result);

    return $thearray;
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. But are you really using `$thearray[] = $title = new Book($title, $author, $description);`? That seems kind of strange, and kind of like it would still be creating a numerically indexed array.

Comment: It is working, but I would definitely be open to doing it a different/better way. I'm quite new to working with the mysqli & php, and often I feel like I'm fudging my way through it trying to learn as I go. What I'm trying to do is develop a mvc for my site to keep things organized better, etc. What happens is I create an array with this function which is passed back into the controller and populates my template (view). I use a foreach() loop to echo out each item in my view. If that makes sense...

Comment: It does make sense. I think the fact that it's working now means that what happens in your view does not really depend on `$thearray` having string keys. What happens when you do `$thearray[] = $title = new Book...` is a multiple assignment. Basically, the new `Book` is created and assigned to the `$title` variable, replacing the string that it was previously holding, and then the new value of `$title` is added into `$thearray`.